# The code is clean but after i run l am geting this error

Tags: dart, flutter

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';  
class CustomIcons {   
     static const IconData favorite = IconData(0xe900, fontFamily: "CustomIcon"); 
     static const IconData search = IconData(0xe901, fontFamily: "CustomIcon");
     static const IconData cart = IconData(0xe903, fontFamily: "CustomIcon"); 
}
```

Comment: What's the error?